# 2 Thess. 2:11; Strong's (G1753, energeia) delusion (G4106, plane); planet energy?

Tags: greek, translation-philosophy, etymology

Don't know much about the root meaning of words, but is what these words could be referring to, like the lie is associated with planet energy?

2 Thessalonians 2:11 KJV

> And for this cause God shall send them **strong delusion**, that they should believe a lie:

Answer (score 1):

Cognates can be fun! But no, this doesn't have anything to do with planet energy.

**Greek**

- STRONGS NT 1753: ἐνέργεια (energeia). Thayer's Greek Lexicon defines is as "working, efficiency; in the N. T. used only of superhuman power, whether of God or of the devil". Further reading [here](https://biblehub.com/greek/1753.htm).
- STRONGS NT 4106: πλάνη (plané). Thayer's Greek Lexicon defines it as "a wandering, a straying about, whereby one, led astray from the right way, roams hither and thither (Aeschylus (Herodotus), Euripides, Plato, Demosthenes, others). In the N. T. metaphorically, mental straying, i. e. error, wrong opinion relative to morals or religion. Further reading [here](https://biblehub.com/greek/4106.htm).

This describes an error that is potent enough to lead people astray.

--

**Astronomy**

This is a misleading cognate because in the ancient world the earth was not considered a planet--to the ancients there were only 5 planets (Mercury, Venus, Mars, Jupiter, Saturn...the rest weren't known until the invention of the telescope), and they were called planets ("wanderers") because unlike the stars, which all consistently appear to move across the sky in the same direction, planets go into [retrograde](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apparent_retrograde_motion) and appear to move backwards with respect to all the other stars.

Thus planets are wanderers but not all wanderers are planets.

Comment: +1.  Good answer.

Comment: So you know how it calls heavenly powers, wondering stars, could this be talking about accessing power through what the Bible calls wondering stars.  What we call planets, like the science of accessing energy derived from these heavenly powers? Or it could be a reference to how the host of heaven will be given over to the little horn in daneil